# generate a new dictionary based on list of values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have an input dictionary d1 and list l1 and want to generate output dictionary d2.

```
d1 = {'A1':['b1','b2','b3'], 'A2':['b2', 'b3'], 'A3':['b1', 'b5']}
l1 = ['b2', 'b5', 'b1', 'b3']
```

Output dictionary

```
d2 = {'b2':['A1','A2'], 'b5':['A3'], 'b1':['A1','A3'], 'b3':['A1','A2']}
```

In output dictionary all values of list l1 act as keys, for the values of dictionary d2 we search the particular key in d1 dictionary values, if this key is present in dictionary values we will select the corresponding key from the dictionaryd1. For example, for key b2, we search it in dictionary values, as it is present in values of 'A1' keys and 'A2' keys, so we select 'A1' and 'A2' from d1. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Reference the accepted answer, replace `set` with `list`, `series` with `d1`,  `d[prop].add(k)` with `d[prop].append(k)`

Comment: list_dict ={}
for i in l1:

    list_dict_keys = []
    for k, j in zip(d1.keys(), d1.values()):
        if(i in j):
            list_dict_keys.append(k)

    # list_dict[i] = list_dict_keys
    list_dict.update({i:list_dict_keys})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple dictionary comprehension with a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> {value: [key for key in d1 if value in d1[key]] for value in l1}
{'b2': ['A1', 'A2'], 'b5': ['A3'], 'b1': ['A1', 'A3'], 'b3': ['A1', 'A2']}
```